# How to conditionally show-hide button in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am using very basic `jQuery Dialog` :

```
$(function () {
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
                        height: 300,
                        width: 450,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "show-hide": function () {
                                $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                            },
                            "Start": function () {
                                $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                            },
                            "Abort": function () {
                                $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                            }
                        },
                        close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                        }
                    });
              })
```

here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7tvdjb/) example even though this is pretty basic. So in my real example the `"show-hide"` button should be shown if a certain condition is met. What I ultimately would like to achieve is something like this:

```
         "show-hide": function () {
           if (someValue == true)
           {
            show button
           }
           else
           {
           hide button
           }
              $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
         }
```

thinking about it such inline definition most probably won't work anyways. But how can I implement this logic for this certain button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the button object to add or remove buttons conditionaly

```
                buttons: $.extend( 
                           //replace false with your variable
                           (false) ? 
                           // if true, adds object with show-hide
                            {"show-hide" : function(){

                             } } : 
                            //else empty object
                            {},
                         //merge with buttons that are permanent
                        {
                        "Start": function () {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                        },
                        "Abort": function () {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                        }
                    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rh7tvdjb/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Buttons in your Dialog vie the Button-Widget of jQuery-UI.

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
                    height: 300,
                    width: 450,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: [{
                      'class' : 'yourClass'  
                       text: "show-hide",
                       click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
                        } 
                    }]
                });
          });
```

I think you can add specific classes to buttons in newer version of jQuery-ui. (The Quotation Marks around class are necessary for e.g. IE because it's a reserved keyword) 
Then you can do:

```
if(somevalue === false){
   $(".yourClass").button("disable");
}else{
   $(".yourClass").button("enable");
}
```

Now you can disable and enable the buttons of your dialog within your conditions.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is the closest working example. Still not sure, how to show-hide this certain button. cna you provide some example how you hide this button (consider that the condition is always false)?